# Why is the json string null when I pass a inner object to Gson().toJson(object) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I convert a object to a json string using Gson in Kotlin.

The var json2 can return correct result, but the var json1 return null,  why?

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import bll.SettingManage
import info.dodata.mirror.R
import model.MSetting
import com.google.gson.Gson
import utility.PreferenceTool

class UIMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main)

        data class WiFiDefA(val Name:String, val Status: String)

        var  aWiFiDefA=WiFiDefA("a","b")
        var  json1=Gson().toJson(aWiFiDefA)

        var aWiFiDefB=WiFiDefB("c","d")
        var json2=Gson().toJson(aWiFiDefB)   

    }

    data class WiFiDefB(val Name:String, val Status: String)

}
```

Comment: write your `WiFiDefA` code outside of the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thanks, why do I need to write WiFiDefA code outside of the onCreate method?

Answer (score 5):

What you observed is a known limitation of Gson: it won't serialize anonymous or local classes. This is why Gson code is explicitly refusing to serialize your class `WiFiDefA`, defined inside the method `onCreate` (this is what @SangeetSuresh observed by debuging the Gson code).

As you can see in https://github.com/google/gson/issues/298, an issue was raised to change that and allow serialization of anonymous and local classes, but the issue was closed more than a year ago without a clear reason.

Answer (score 4):

I have gone through Gson Library and found that following code

```
if (isAnonymousOrLocal(clazz)) {
      return true;
    }
```

`isAnonymousOrLocal(clazz)` is returning `true` for `WiFiDefA` and inside that method `clazz.isLocalClass()` is returning true

But for `WiFiDefB`, these functions are returning false.

For more info, please visit below link

https://github.com/google/gson/blob/0636635cbffa08157bdbd558b1212e4d806474eb/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/Excluder.java

Comment: Thanks, do you mean that  the class can be defined in function?

Comment: Only Gson maybe cause error when the class is defined in function?

Comment: @HelloCW If you define class inside function, then it will become local class to that function. So scope will be restricted to that function. You can access class only within that function. Gson reply on generics. It will access class from their function. Since it is not accessible, it's giving error.

Answer (score 0):

As I have tried with GSON lib, I have declared both classes outside of the `onCreate()` method.

Like below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val  aWiFiDefA=WiFiDefA("a","b")
    val json1=Gson().toJson(aWiFiDefA)

    Log.d("json1",json1.toString())
    var aWiFiDefB=WiFiDefB("c","d")
    var json2= Gson().toJson(aWiFiDefB)
    Log.d("json2",json2.toString())
}
data class WiFiDefA(val Name:String, val Status: String)
data class WiFiDefB(val Name:String, val Status: String)
```

Which gives me an output which you required.
Output:

```
11-17 11:58:50.448 27978-27978/? D/json1: {"Name":"a","Status":"b"}
11-17 11:58:50.452 27978-27978/? D/json2: {"Name":"c","Status":"d"}
```

But when I have tried your code getting output like below:

```
11-17 11:58:01.312 27584-27584/? D/json1: null
11-17 11:58:01.320 27584-27584/? D/json2: {"Name":"c","Status":"d"}
```

We can not create class into method scope. You can create [Nested and Inner Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#nested-and-inner-classes) a class as a nested class if you want.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html#nested-and-inner-classes

Comment: Thanks! Do mean that it cause problem when I create a class in method scope? but the code can  be compiled! so why can't I create a class in method scope?

Comment: Any ideas for me?

Comment: AFAIK, Do mean that it causes problem when I create a class in method scope? **yes** . Because kotlin can only suggest `normal`, `nested` and `inner` way classes as I have added in the answer. Sure will let u know If any other solution is there. Thanks 

Comment: Thanks, my question is why the class can be defined in function but it cause error result!